# Google developer console - add multiple translations to app store listening

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I have an app title and description that i translated into multiple languages.

I dont want to update the translations manually because i have many of them.

Is there a way to uoload some kind of json file of all the translations?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Play Console, you can only write your own translations. If you want to automatise the process, you can purchase translations from Google, nothing more.

Comment: I have a JSON file with translations that I made, and it contains around 20 translations.
is there a way I can upload this json file into google play console and update the translations of a specific package?
I dont want to automate anything, because I hvae the translations, I just want to upload them at once.

Comment: I understood your request, but this step of uploading a JSON file is part of an automatisation process which does not exists. If you could do that, they obviously would make an API endpoint to do this from an external tool. So no, you have to copy paste each language.